# When does a moment generating function exist?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, moment-generating-functions

Does an MGF $M(t)$ exist if it is finite only at $t=0$?

I read that an MGF exists if it is finite on some open interval $(-a,a)$ containing $0$. I'm not sure if $0$ alone counts as such an open interval!

---

The reason I ask this question is because I'm working through an example which asks if the moment generating function of a Weibull distribution with $\lambda=1$ and $\gamma=\frac{1}{3}$ exists.

Let $T=X^3$ with $X \sim Exp(1)$. Then

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{tT} \right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{tX^3} \right]
 = \int_0^{\infty} e^{tx^3-x}\ dx.
$$

The example says that this integral diverges for $t>0$, so the MGF of $T$ does not exist. However, I think that the integral does not diverge for $t\leq 0$, and I would expect that this would be enough for the MGF to exist.

Could anybody shed some light on this please?

Comment: I would think based on this definition, $M(t)$ will be well-defined at $t \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know if the point 0 is an example of "some open interval (−,) containing 0"? If it is not, that could be the reason for the discrepancy between my thinking and the answer from the book (the book is Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein and Hwang)?

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is a closed set. It needs to be finite in some neighbourhood around 0, i.e. on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ (can be very small). Btw, the mgf is always finite at 0 (it equals 1). See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211706/what-does-it-mean-for-a-moment-generating-function-to-exist-in-a-neighborhood-of

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)